# Setting ctrl with V4L2 on ov5640

Tags: c++, v4l2

I would like to control various `ov5640` camera parameters by using `ioctl` and `VIDIOC_S_CTRL` from V4L2 in the following manner:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>

#define IOCTL_TRIES 3
#define CLEAR(x) memset (&(x), 0, sizeof (x))

static int xioctl(int fd, int request, void *arg)
{
    int r;
    int tries = IOCTL_TRIES;

    do {
        r = ioctl(fd, request, arg);
    } while (--tries > 0 && r == -1 && EINTR == errno);

    return r;
}

bool v4l2_ctrl_set(int fd, uint32_t id, int val)
{
    struct v4l2_control ctrl;
    CLEAR(ctrl);

    ctrl.id = id;
    ctrl.value = val;
    if (xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &ctrl) == -1) {
        std::cout << "Failed to set ctrl with id " 
                  << id << " to value " << val
                  << "\nerror (" << errno << "): " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{

    int fd = open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd == -1) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open the camera" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    v4l2_ctrl_set(fd, V4L2_CID_SATURATION, 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately `ioctl` fails and I get `error (25): Inappropriate ioctl for device`. I'm using [Intrinsyc Open-Q 820 µSOM](https://www.intrinsyc.com/computing-platforms/open-q-820-usom/) with [linaro 4.14](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/tree/?h=release%2Fqcomlt-4.14). I've managed to add some debugs prints to ov5640 driver file in [ov5640_s_ctrl function](https://git.linaro.org/landing-teams/working/qualcomm/kernel.git/tree/drivers/media/i2c/ov5640.c?h=release/qcomlt-4.14#n1923) before `if (sensor->power_count == 0) {` (in case there were problems with power save mode) and recompile the kernel. I ran the code, but looking through `dmesg` my `printk` message doesn't get printed, so that means that `ov5640_s_ctrl` doesn't get called even though the callback is set:

```
static const struct v4l2_ctrl_ops ov5640_ctrl_ops = {
    .g_volatile_ctrl = ov5640_g_volatile_ctrl,
    .s_ctrl = ov5640_s_ctrl,
};
```

Am I using V4L2 wrong? Should I enable something before setting the controls? It's even more confusing since I manage to get an image from the camera with v4l2, but I can't set/get any controls.

Comment: looking at the kernel source code of ov5640.c you supplied, the driver has the flag `V4L2_SUBDEV_FL_HAS_DEVNODE`, which means it supplies a `/dev/v4l-subdevX` . Maybe you can try to set the control directly from the v4l-subdevX node,

Comment: That's right, controlling the device through v4l subdev node works. Can you change this comment to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the the kernel source code of ov5640.c that you supplied, the driver is assigned the flag `V4L2_SUBDEV_FL_HAS_DEVNODE` which means it might supply a subdev node  `/dev/v4l-subdevX`. According to the kernel docs:

> Device nodes named v4l-subdevX can be created in /dev to access sub-devices directly. If a sub-device supports direct userspace configuration it must set the V4L2_SUBDEV_FL_HAS_DEVNODE flag before being registered.`

So you can try to set the control directly from the v4l-subdevX node if it exists.